# Facebook Android SDK, UiLifecycleHelper StackOverflow error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Getting a strange StackOverflow error from UiLifecycleHelper. It looks like it's trying to load a serialized object, but then the ObjectInputStream runs into a recursive loop, possibly due to corrupt data. It only happens in the onCreate method. Here's the stack trace

**Update**

The StackOverflowError actually also occurs in onSaveInstance state, but loops in ObjectStream writes. We do have only 4 crash logs showing this though, with 49 crash logs on the read in onCreate. Here's the code that's being used:

The uiHelper is called in all of it's expected methods, onCreate, onResume, onPause, onSaveInstanceState, onDestroy with no straying from the docs at all. All the other Facebook code used is shown below.

```
//onClick facebook button
private void facebook() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        Log.v("W", "Already have session");
        publishog(session);
    } else {

        Session.openActiveSession(WWhisperActivity.this, true, callback);
    }
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception e) {
    if (e != null && !e.getLocalizedMessage().contains("user denied")) {
        BugSenseHandler.sendException(e);
    }
    if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENING)) {
        Log.v("W", "Session opening state");
    } else if (state.equals(SessionState.CREATED)
            || state.equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        Log.v("W", "Session created state");
    }
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.v("W", "Open session");
        if (!session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
            Log.v("W", "Getting publish permission");
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest r = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(r);
        } else {
            Log.v("W", "Session opened, publishing og");
            publishog(session);
        }
    } else if (state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED)
            || state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED)) {
        Log.v("W", "Session not open");
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        if (state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED)) {
            if (e == null || !e.getLocalizedMessage().contains("abort")
                    && !e.getLocalizedMessage().contains("user denied"))
                Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
        }
    }
}

private void publishog(Session session) {
    Log.v("W", "Publishing OG");
    WObject wo = GraphObject.Factory.create(WObject.class);
    wo.setId(w.wid);
    wo.setUrl(shorturl);
    WOGShare ws = GraphObject.Factory.create(WOGShare.class);
    ws.setWhisper(shorturl);
    com.facebook.Request.executePostRequestAsync(session,
            "me/whisper_app:share", ws,
            new com.facebook.Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    if (response.getError() != null) {

                    } else {

                    }

                }

            });
}
```

The crash log:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
1at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:65)
2at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getCache(ObjectStreamClass.java:1093)
3at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1066)
4at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1037)
5at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:248)
6at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1069)
7at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1037)
8at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:248)
9at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1069)
10at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1037)
11at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:248)
12at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1069)
13at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2375)
14at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1662)
15at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
16at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1803)
17at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
18at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
19at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
20at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
21at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
22at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
23at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
24at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
25at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
26at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
27at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
28at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
29at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
30at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
31at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
32at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
33at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
34at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
35at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
36at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
37at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
38at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
39at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
40at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
41at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
42at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
43at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
44at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
45at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
46at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
47at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
48at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
49at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
50at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
51at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
52at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
53at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
54at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
55at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
56at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
57at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
58at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
59at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
60at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
61at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
62at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
63at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
64at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
65at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
66at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
67at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
68at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
69at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
70at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
71at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
72at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
73at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
74at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
75at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
76at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
77at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
78at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
79at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
325at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
326at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
327at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
328at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
329at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
330at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
331at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
332at com.facebook.Session.restoreSession(Session.java:701)
333at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onCreate(UiLifecycleHelper.java:70)
334at sh.whisper.WWhisperActivity.onCreate(WWhisperActivity.java:279)
335at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5160)
336at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
337at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
338at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
339at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
340at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
341at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
342at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
343at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
344at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
345at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
346at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
347at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)

348at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your code? You might be trying to run an open request manually or something while the uiHelper automatically runs another request due to a session state change.

Comment: Posted, haven't been able to replicate the StackOverflow though

Comment: Has anybody else seen this? This is happening quite often in our application.

Comment: Did you initialized UiLifeCycleHelper in onCreate method?   uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: i got it buddy check here :).


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093462/having-trouble-creating-a-certain-class-in-java

Answer (score 1):

> Parameters and local variables are allocated on the stack (with
>   reference types the object lives on the heap and a variable references
>   that object). The stack typically lives at the upper end of your
>   address space and as it is used up it heads towards the bottom of the
>   address space (ie towards zero).
>
> gui programming it's possible to generate indirect recursion. For
>   example, your app may be handling paint messages and whilst processing
>   them it may call a function that causes the system to send another
>   paint message. Here you've not explicitly called yourself, but the
>   OS/VM has done it for you.

I have encountered the same error before.Do one thing just remove any initialization directly below the class and move it inside `onCreate()` or `onResume()`.

Comment: I did just this. It looks like it *decreased* occurrence of the crash, but it hasn't been eliminated. Also, this StackOverflow isn't generated due to a GUI loop, it's due to a Serialized Object loop, likely due to a request permission loop or a possible issue with Facebook's implicitly defined JSON Object interface types.